# How can I use Bluetooth on my computer?

Tags: windows-7

What is the requirement to be able to use Bluetooth in Windows 7?

Comment: I was going to edit this to readability and then answer with "You need a bluetooth adapter that's compatible with Windows 7 installed and nothing else" but then I saw it was tagged 'firefox' so maybe it's even more cryptic than it seems?  Can you please explain what you mean further?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please include more details in to your question, it's unclear as it is and tagging it as Firefox doesn't really help us to get a clue. Afterwards, you can flag the question and ask for it to be reponened.

Answer (score 3):

If your computer does not have an internal bluetooth adapter, you can buy a USB bluetooth adapter (also called "[dongle](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/File:BluetoothUSB.jpg)"). If you have an internal adapter, but it does not work, make sure you installed the drivers.

If you want to use bluetooth to connect to your mobile phone, you probably want to install the software that came with your phone as well.

Short answer to your question:

- a win7 compatible adapter
- drivers
- (software, although not mandatory)

Comment: When purchasing external bluetooth adapters it is a good idea to see if they come with software. Windows does have its own bluetooth stack but there are other stacks which provide more capabilities. Some adapters do come with a stack while others do not. Cost of purchasing license for bluetooth software stack is usually several times higher than cost of a bluetooth adapter, so it is generally smart idea to look for adapters which come with a stack included, because they are considerably cheaper than separate purchase of a bluetooth adapter and license for a stack.